# need help for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

When I save data byte[] in SQL Server the value change and add 0x0 in the first of value
the correct value (`0xFFD8FFE000104A46`)

the incorrect value (`0x0FFD8FFE000104A46494600010102004C`)

Comment: Please update your post with the code you are using. And tag the database engine (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.).

Comment: Can you post your `INSERT` statement and the definition for your table/column please?

Comment: Please edit the question, show your relevant code and table definition.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

0xF and 0x0F are the same number, both are hexadecimal notations of number 15 decimal. A byte contains two hexadecimal 'digits'. If the left most digit is 0, it doesn't affect the value, just like zero-hundred and fifteen is the same as fifteen. The notation with the leading 0 just prints all the bytes, the one without strips the leading zeros.

Where the 494600010102004C part is coming from I don't know.